Binding to a property of object within of ObservableCollection of objects
I have a MainWindow that contains a DataGrid with togglebuttons, the DataGrid's itemsource is ObservableCollection of objects. I want to following: when user check the toggle the IsActive2 will inkove it's set. but now it's not happening and I can't see why.
here MainWindow xaml:
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- Define a DataGridTemplateColumn -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Toggle Column">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Use a ToggleButton in the cell template -->
                        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsActive2, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Toggle" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>

here code behind:
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TestObj> _myList;
    public ObservableCollection<TestObj> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
            _myList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyList));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyList = new ObservableCollection<TestObj> { new TestObj(), new TestObj(), new TestObj() };
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

here TestObj:
 public class TestObj : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     private bool _isActive;

     public bool IsActive2
     {
         get { return _isActive; }
         set
         {
             _isActive = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsActive2)); 
         }
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
 }


Adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged solved the problem
